# How to use vi/vim/gvim seamlessly with visual studio 2008?

Tags: vim

I tried viEmu trial version but it failed to start.
Please give some alternate suggestions??

Comment: I've used viEmu in 2008 and it has worked fine.  Did it throw any errors, or just completely fail to start?

Comment: It threw some error pop up. After giving some time to fix , i unistalled it.I found a lot of people on google having the same prob.

Comment: what kind of alternative?  Don't use viEmu?  Use a different vi emulator? If you want suggestions on fixing the error, the actual error message would help :)

Answer (score 3):

Stick with it and get ViEmu working -- you really get the best of both VI and VS.  The guy who makes it, Jon, is really nice and very helpful.  Contact him through the site and he'll help you get it going and probably extend your trial for you.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `visual_studio.vim` script to integrate gvim and Visual Studio, depending on what version you're using.  The vim Wikia has more information: [`http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Integrate_gvim_with_Visual_Studio`](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Integrate_gvim_with_Visual_Studio)